# Nightwatch setvalue method not working at all

Tags: ui-automation, nightwatch.js, browser-automation

I am new to NightWatch and trying to use .setValue method to enter email/password on http://app.insight360.io

It simply fails to set the value. I have tried waitForElementPresent and waitForElementVisible to see if that helps, but nothing seems to be working.

I would love it if somebody can post a code snippet that would set the value to any string you like in the email and password field and click the Login button.

Comment: Hey there Harv! Can you update your question with the snippet you used? We can start from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to input email and password and click on Login button with the below snippet, using **setValue**. Can you once try and let me know.

```
module.exports = {

    'DemoTest 1': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('https://app.insight360.io/')
            .waitForElementVisible('.input.ng-valid-email:nth-child(1)', 5000)
            .setValue('.input.ng-valid-email:nth-child(1)', 'abc@text.com')
            .setValue('div.form-wrapper > form > div:nth-child(2) > input', 'password123')
            .click('.button.highlight-primary:nth-child(1)')
            .end()
    },

};
```